# Selenium WebDriver, Java: how to determine if a page is fully loaded by comparing two elements?

Tags: java, regex, selenium, xpath

**Background**

I am using Selenium WebDriver/Java to scrape a table. The table I am interested in is divided into many separate pages (= one must click a link to see the next page). At the bottom of the table is an incomplete numerical index (The whole table is 170+ pages. When you are on one of the first 20 pages, the index contains links to page 1-20, when you are on page 21-40 the index contains links to page 21-40 etc) where you can click on a specific number to load that page. The whole index is in one cell, like this [1](http://dummy.com) [2](http://dummy.com)...[20](http://dummy.com). There are also links to *First*, *Previous* page, *Next* and *Last* page.

The number of/link to the current page has a specific class (*CurrentPage*). I browse through each of these pages by clicking *Next* and here is the problem: how do I verify that the table has finished loading when I go to the next page?

Usually in this project, to verify that a page is fully loaded before Selenium proceeds I use something like this code:

```
webDriverBackedSelenium.click(xpathToSomeLink);
new WebDriverWait(driver, normalTimeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathToSomeElemen)));
```

Now to my problem/the question: I have been unable to write an XPath that I can use in the code above. I guess that what I need is to, after Selenium clicks a link, look at the content of an `A`-tag that has the class *CurrentPage* and verify that it has changed (+1) compared to before the click.

I found what looked like a good example of how to write XPaths that target the content of a tag here http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/xpath.html#selecting-by-tag-content but when I run their example `//h:h2[re:test(., 'chapter|section', 'i')]` in Firebug/Firepath I just receive an error message that the XPath is invalid. Why? What is wrong with their example? And how do I write an XPath I that can distinguish between these two situations (first case I am on page 21, in the second example I am on page 22):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="CurrentPage" href="javascript:doPostBack('XXX')">21</a>
            <a class="OtherPage" href="javascript:doPostBack('XXX')">22</a>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="OtherPage" href="javascript:doPostBack('XXX')">21</a>
            <a class="CurrentPage" href="javascript:doPostBack('XXX')">22</a>
```

A final note: I am using Selenium to scrape data from a website, that is, redesigning it to make the above easier is not an option.

Comment: you can use `find_element_by_partial_link_text`.You can give `page` or something which is constant and leave the variable part.

Comment: Can I somehow qualify it using XPath? Because the table I am working with is full of numbers and, mostly between 0 and 100, hence it is a big risk that the page number and some data in the table coincide.

Comment: @user23122 what is the *actual* question? Do you want an Xpath that return `<a>` element having class attribute equals `CurrentPage`? `//a[@class='CurrentPage']`

Comment: I want to verify that the page loaded successfully after Selenium clicks the Next link.

Comment: @user23122 You know the solution ("*.....verify that it has changed (+1)....*"). So what is the *specific* question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this XPath construction `//a[.='17']` and something like the following code (slightly simplified):

```
int nextPageNumber = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath(linkActivePage)).getText()) + 1)
String xpathToNextPage = "xPathPrefix + "a[.='" + nextPageNumber + "']";
webDriverBackedSelenium.click(linkNextPage);
new WebDriverWait(driver, normalTimeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathToNextPage)));
```

Seems to work fine but I welcome comments on how to improve it!

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only two tags then use a css selector instead and thats easier. The number of child can be controlled by a simple loop

td a:nth-child(2)

Comment: There are 19 entries that with the same CSS class. Can you elaborate how the loop would work?

Comment: you should be able to narrow it down with the :nth-child() as well.

Comment: Even though I don't suggest you to do that but you can loop through those 19 elements and use an if clause that matches the number you wanted and click. If you need more help elaborate your html and I can help you finding the selector

Answer (score 0):

So your it seems like there's two questions:

1. *I need an xpath for the element.*
2. *How do I make sure the page has loaded*

A1. xpath would be:

```
//a[@class='CurrentPage']
```

A2. Wait for an element on the page to be visible, something like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //wait however long to ensure it should be loaded
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("CurrentPage")));
```